# DynamoDB eventually consistence read ordering for sequential written data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have an application which append events to `dynamodb table` with `userid` as a hashkey and incremental seq number as range key(to guarantee the sort order). Table is append only.lets say writer write events for userid '1'. I have a reader that read events using last sequence number with user id '1' hash key.
If reader used strong consistence reads I know reader will get the data sequentially as same as write sequence.

If reader used eventually consistence reads ,can I expect the same behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You *can not expect* the same behavior in that items that were written last might not be available to an eventually consistent read.

Say for example you have 3 writes in a row:

```
userId=1, seqNumber=1
userId=1, seqNumber=2
userId=1, seqNumber=3
```

If you do an eventually consistent read, you are not guaranteed to get all of the items. Your query would still return the items in order if that is how you are insert items. If you want to get all of the most recent writes, you have to use a strongly consistent read.

From the [DynamoDB FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/)

> ...
>
> Eventually Consistent Reads (Default) – the eventual consistency
>   option maximizes your read throughput. However, an eventually
>   consistent read might not reflect the results of a recently completed
>   write. Consistency across all copies of data is usually reached within
>   a second. Repeating a read after a short time should return the
>   updated data
>
> ...

Comment: i don't mind getting latest writes little bit later ,as long as it guaranteed write order.if you can confirm that i can accept your answer.

Comment: @nsa I don't understand what you mean by write order. It is up to your application to deal with the sequencing of the items. In the example I gave, your application needs to write 3 items with `seqNumber=n`. It is up to your how you want to determine the `n` before you write items to DynamoDB.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. what i mean was i want to read data order by sequence number.in this case it is the same as write order.